# How exactly does dispatching to 'self' and 'super' work?

Tags: objective-c

Please help me making this clear about instance methods in Objective C:

- Can send messages to `self` and `super` inside

  - both dispatch the message to the calling object, but use different implementations
  - if a superclass of yours calls a method on `self`, it will [execute] your implementation (if one exists)

[Lecture 3, Stanford University, Objectve-C course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%203_0.pdf)

Comment: Could you at least copy the quote down from the lecture correctly? I can't understand your version.

Comment: It IS copied literally from the lecture... It's talking about instance methods by the way

Page 9 at that link

Comment: No it wasn't. It was unintelligible without the correct formatting. (Thanks @sch)

Comment: But is that related to the title you changed to?...

And I still don't understand this .___.

if a superclass of yours calls a method on self, it will [execute] your implementation (if one exists)

Comment: I didn't edit the title originally, but this new one should do.

Comment: That's perfect editing :) Thanks much yuji :)

Comment: Why don't you watch the videos in [iTunes U](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255)?

Comment: I already do by the way. But I revise them using the pdf files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now that it's actually possible to understand the question:

Let's say you have a class `Foo` with methods `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`, and you make a subclass of `Foo` called `Bar`.

In your implementation of `Bar`, if you wanted to call `doSomething` you could either do `[self doSomething]` or `[super doSomething]`.

- `[super doSomething]` would use the superclass's implementation of `doSomething`—specifically, `Foo`'s implementation.
- `[self doSomething]` would use the class itself's implementation of `doSomething`—that is, `Bar`'s implementation. Note that  if `Bar` didn't actually override `doSomething`, then `[self doSomething]` would end up calling the superclass's implementation.

As for what happens if a superclass calls a method on `self`, let's say `Bar` overrides `doSomething`, but doesn't override `doSomethingElse`, and let's say `doSomethingElse` looks like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingElse
{
    [self doSomething];
}
```

What happens if you call `doSomethingElse` on `Foo *aFoo` and `Bar *aBar`? The result of `[aFoo doSomethingElse]` is clear: it does `[self doSomething]` where `self` is a `Foo`, so `Foo`'s implementation of `doSomething` will be executed.

But when you do `[aBar doSomethingElse]` is where things get interesting, and is what Paul was getting at. since `Bar` doesn't override `doSomethingElse`, `Foo`'s implementation will be called, which in turn does `[self doSomething]`. But this time, `self` is an instance of `Bar`, and so `Bar`'s implementation of doSomething will be called.

Why would `[self doSomething]` in the implementation of `Foo` end up executing code from the subclass `Bar`? This is because of how messages are dispatched in Objective-C. `[self doSomething]` sends the message `doSomething` to the object `self`, and it is up to whatever object `self` is to decide what code gets executed. Since `self`, in this situation, would be a `Bar`, `Bar`'s implementation of `doSomething` is executed.

Comment: That twisted my head over .___.

Beginning from here:

So when Bar calls doSomethingElse, it actually executes the superclass's doSomethingElse, which in turn makes the superclass call [self doSomething], but that ends up executing the subclass' implementation of doSomething, not the superclass's.

Doesn't it call the superclass's one? then superclass calls itself? Then why is the subclass one executed?

Comment: @TheNavigator just try it and see for yourself. It's so easy to do that anyway.

Comment: So if Bar has an implementation of that message, it will override Foo. If not, then Foo would work, because of inheritance

Is that right?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I want to understand how does it work first :|

Comment: AT LAST! Thanks Yuji! :)

Oh, last question, then how to "force" Foo's message to work?

Comment: I don't think you can; if you have a situation where you want the superclass to always use its own implementation of something, then you should probably hide the method (keep it out of the .h) or explicitly tell people not to override it.